# Transaction runs out of gas with MetaMask on a simple function

Tags: truffle, gas, metamask, out-of-gas

MetaMask calculated automatically the gas needed for every transaction, but for one in particular, it always returns the error "out of gas" if I use the default amount.

The function is really simple so I don't get how it can run out of gas:

```
mapping (uint => xyz) public xyzs;

function setXyzParameters(uint id, uint newPrice, bool _isForSale) public {
    require(msg.sender == xyzs[id].creator);
    xyzs[id].price = newPrice;
    xyzs[id].isForSale = _isForSale;
}
```

On my private node, MetaMask sets by default a gas limit of 27043 and it fails if I leave it at that, 30000 still fails but it works 40000.

What am I doing wrong?

**Additional info:** Turns out the amount of gas is different if the boolean is true or false. I guess when it's false some part of the Tx data is `00000000` while it's more info if it's true, so maybe that's why the estimated gas is different.

---

(To give context, I'm working on something based on the [Truffle tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop))